# Sharepoint 2010 Remove Groups From Add Links dialog for MyLInks Webpart

Tags: branding

In Add Link dialog box of MyLinks web part, I need to remove few options from "Existing group" and "Show links to" dropdowns. All options which are being displayed for these fields are out of box. I need to display 'Only Me' option for "Show these links to" field. Similarly I need to show only "General" and "Best Bets" options for "Grouping" field. Do you know if there is a way to remove unwanted options from these fields?

Here is the screenshot of the dialog box where these drop down fields displayed.

[Add Link Dialog](http://blogs.kma-llc.net/.a/6a0115709993d0970b014e8b5c410e970d-pi)

Answer (score 1):

There's three options there.

Firstly, check the policies under your User Profiles Service App. Maybe there's an option to change it there.

Secondly, if this is going to be a permanent change, then you can just go look for the ASPX page for Add Links, and edit the aspx to remove the options you dont want.

Third option would be to create your own Page with only the options you want to see and show your own aspx in the add links modal.